# eventnews - exception class EventNewsRowInitializeNew not found

Tags: typo3

i get the following error message in the backend:

Class 'GeorgRinger\Eventnews\Backend\FormDataProvider\EventNewsRowInitializeNew' not found

I run into the exception when i try to edit the page or open the template tool. So i cannot activate the static setup.

The file EventNewsRowInitializeNew.php is where it belongs: 
/typo3conf/ext/eventnews/Classes/Backend/FormDataProvider/EventNewsRowInitializeNew.php

The psr-4 definition in composer.lock seems correct:

```
"autoload": {
     "psr-4": {
          "GeorgRinger\\Eventnews\\": "Classes"
      }
},
```

TYPO3 8.7.9
News 6.2.1
eventnews 2.0.1
PHP 7.1.9 on mittwald server
Installation with composer

What i tried:

- clearing all caches in install tool
- deinstall and install the extensions once again

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `composer dump` to rebuild the autoloader?

Comment: Hi Thomas, no, i did not know this command. I deleted all extensions and let composer rebuild all from scratch. I presume rebuilding the autoloader would be the correct solution ... :-) Therefore i mark your answer as solution. Thanks!!